# playwright (Python) click in a seemingly generated frame?

Tags: python, playwright

I'm trying to use playwright to interact with a page from a device.  From the initial page presented by the device I select the tab I want from the html I see using inspect with

```
page.click('id=laConfig')
```

for the displayed code snippet

```
<div id="nav" class="nav" style="width: 974px;">
        <span class="menu" id="iMenu3" onclick="ChangeFrame('log.asp',3)">
            <label id="laLog" name="laLog" class="mousepointer">Log</label>
        </span>
        <span class="menu menuBackground" id="iMenu4" onclick="ChangeFrame('paramconfig.asp',4)">
            <label id="laConfig" name="laConfig" class="mousepointer">Configuration</label>
        </span>
        <span class="logout" onclick="GoAway()">
            <label id="laExit" name="laExit" class="mousepointer">Logout</label>
        </span> 
    </div>
```

This causes the page I want to load and the parameter config frame loads.  But I don't know how to go farther.  In inspect I can see this code

```
<iframe frameborder="0" scrolling="no" id="contentframe" name="contentframe" class="contentframe" src="paramconfig.asp" style="height: 619px; width: 938px;"></iframe>
```

which makes me think it is generated from a paramconfig.asp file

I next want to select the time settings which is a button I hover over and then click in the displayed page but neither of the following selectors work:

```
page.click('text=Time Settings')
page.click('id=aTimeSettings')
```

What is also strange is I can't copy the code I see in inspect using a right click and copy command in inspect.  I see the code below which I've captured in a screenshot which is how I got the text and ID above.

What do I need to do in playwright to cause it to click the time setting button the same way I do when I'm accessing the device as a user via its web page?

[time setting html from inspect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WfMW3.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use page.click for elements which are on a different page (in an iframe). You need to [get a handle on the frame](https://playwright.dev/python/docs/api/class-page/#page-frame) and interact with that.

Something like:

```
frame = page.frame(name="frame-name")
frame.click("the selector of the element you want to click inside the frame")
```

Something which might give you some inspiration for the correct selectors and so on is [the codegen feature of Playwright](https://playwright.dev/python/docs/cli#generate-code). From the docs though, it looks like it generates JavaScript so really only for inspiration.

(P.S. No experience with Python here)

Comment: thanks, this gave me the hints I needed to get it working.